# Bluetooth RfComm connect failed on samsung

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have device with HeadSet, A2DP and rfcomm profile.
When I connects to device via RfComm (phone and device have already connected) on Samsung (I have Samsung Nexus S) standart connect(A2DP, RFCOMM) breaks down (disconnect).

```
socked.connect();
```

It doesn't appears on HTC.

Maybe someone had this error or know solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the workaround with reflection?

```
int portnumber = //what ever port you are connecting to
Method m = device.getClass().getMethod("createInsecureRfcommSocket", new Class[] {int.class});
tmp = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, portnumber);
```